# ClearCase - Get all elements where two labels are not equal

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

When we start working on a new release we usually put a new label, for example `REL2`, on all elements with label `REL1`. This means that in the beginning of developing a new release, these two versions are identical. As the development progress and elements are checked in, `REL2` will be moved to a newer version.

At the end of the development, `REL2` can differ a lot from `REL1`.

My question is, how do I get all elements where `REL2` are not the same version as `REL1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to look for visible versions which have the `REL2` label but not the `REL1` label.

```
cleartool find . -cview -version "{!lbtype(REL1) && lbtype(REL2)} -print
```

See more examples at "[Additional examples of the `cleartool find` command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)".